# I have a single table format used by 2 independent groups of people, do I make 2 tables or 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 set of data about products, both have the same columns but each I used by a different independent group of users.

I'm not sure if I should store the 2 categories data together or separately.

If I put it in 1 table it'd look like

```
dbo.Products
ID | ..... | Catagory
```

If I do 2 tables.

```
Cat1.Products
ID | .....
Cat2.Prodcuts
ID | .....
```

Edit: The categories both use the same columns.

Comment: If the products are the exact same then I'd suggest 1 table. You could create a different table that controls which items in the category table the users in groups see. 
I'm best guessing which what you have posted in the OP.

Comment: If the same columns, I suggest having one table in the database. Then using views, or maybe in the code, you can do whatever you like.

Comment: @Andy Eewardes, actually, can you clean up the post and clarify the 2nd half where it starts with .... I'm not sure if I should... Need more information.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options depending upon your architecture and your, or your clients, needs.

1. If your clients use the same interface to access the data and the data is separate or can possibly be shared then, for simplicity, you should use the same tables.

   *Caveat*: If the data contains sensitive information (such as personally identifiable data: SSNs, Names, Addresses, etc.) that should only ever be accessible to the owner of that data, then you should seriously consider cloning the table structure to a new database owner, instance, or schema to reduce the chance of any data breaches.
2. If your clients use different interfaces, or different instances of the interface that could potentially diverge from the originating code-base, then you should create a different set of tables under a different database owner, instance, or schema.

There are, of course, other mitigating factors, but I think those are the main things to consider.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if they also share the same data and are related with each other, to keep it simple it's better to do only one if the data and usage are the same.